# Read and edit the file from Java

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to introduce a line break at every 100th character of the line from the existing file.But it doesn't write anything to it. below is the code written in java to read the existing file and write to it with a temporary file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReplaceFileContents {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new ReplaceFileContents().replace();
   }

   public void replace() {
      String oldFileName = "Changed1.ldif";
      String tmpFileName = "Changed2.ldif";

      BufferedReader br = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
         String line;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {       
                line.replaceAll("(.{100})", "$1\n");       
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         return;
      } finally {
         try {
            if(br != null)
               br.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
         try {
            if(bw != null)
               bw.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
      }
      // Once everything is complete, delete old file..
      File oldFile = new File(oldFileName);
      oldFile.delete();

      // And rename tmp file's name to old file name
      File newFile = new File(tmpFileName);
      newFile.renameTo(oldFile);

   }
}
```

Comment: Do not silence the `Exception` !! try out output them on the console.

Comment: You are not writing to `bw` anywhere

Comment: instead of reading and processing the file line by line,  why not just read one byte at a time whilst keeping track of the bytes consumed and once the count reaches 100 append a new line.

Comment: Final note: read about try-with-resources. With recent versions of java, you don't need all that manual closing of writers/readers/...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {       
    line.replaceAll("(.{100})", "$1\n");       
}
```

First off, `line.replaceAll` does not replace your line variable with the result. Because `Strings` are immutable, this method returns the new string, so your line should be `line = line.replaceAll(...`.

Second, you're never writing the new `String` back into the file. Using `replaceAll` doesn't change the file itself in any way. Instead, try using your `bw` object to write the new `String` to the same line.

Comment: Thanks It writes.But what I really expected is to have a line break say after 4th character.
Input
-----
abcdef
gh
ijklmn


output
------
abcd
ef
gh
ijkl
mn

but the above codes writes all in a single line.

Comment: `BufferedReader.read` will read one character at a time. `BufferedWriter.write` will write without making a new line afterward.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've published here, you never try to write `line` back to `bw`. Try this:

```
package hello;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().replace();
    }

    public void replace() {
        String oldFileName = "d:\\1.txt";
        String tmpFileName = "d:\\2.txt";

        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.replaceAll("(.{100})", "$1\n");
                bw.write(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //
            }
            try {
                if(bw != null)
                    bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //
            }
        }
        // Once everything is complete, delete old file..
        File oldFile = new File(oldFileName);
        oldFile.delete();

        // And rename tmp file's name to old file name
        File newFile = new File(tmpFileName);
        newFile.renameTo(oldFile);

    }
}
```

1. You never try to write line back to `bw`;
2. `String#replaceAll` will return the copy of the source not the original `String`;